# Reference 1 Google Sheet to another

Tags: reference, google-sheets

I have 2 sheets here:
**Sheet 1** - image 1 and
**P.O.** - image 2

What I would love to happen is that when I choose "**Y**" from Column **A**(**Sheet 1**) dropdown, then the Data from the **ADJACENT ROW** in Column A -*COLUMNS C and D from the same sheet(Sheet 1)*- will be populated/copied to the other sheet(**PO**).

So, it would be **Sheet 1 Column C** Data going to *PO Sheet Column A*, and **Sheet 1 Column D** Data going to *PO Sheet Column B*.

I have tried using my own IF code but it did not work.
    =IF('Sheet 1'!A8:A="Y",(A2=B8,""))

Thank you,
All help will be greatly appreciated.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw6Ul.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OJIM.png
```

Comment: it's like, when the drop down is changed to Y, then the data beside it will automatically be copied to the other sheet.. Hope this helps.. Would be more than willing to provide more info for clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is messed up.

Po A2=

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Sheet 1'!A8:A="Y", 'Sheet 1'!C8:C,""))
```

A better formula for Google sheets would be: Po A2=

```
=FILTER({'Sheet 1'!C8:C,'Sheet 1'!D8:D},'Sheet 1'!A8:A="Y")
```

Note that the last solution will not work in other inferior spreadsheet solutions, notably, Microsoft Excel.

Comment: If it works, mark this as solution by clicking ☑✔✓✅ on the left of this post. –